# Time/Clock doesn't refresh automatically in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

This is really weird. I am using a Windows 10 Enterprise which has all possible updates. The clock/time (in the lower right corner) doesn't refresh itself automatically. For example, if the current time is 3:00pm and I just let the computer sit there without doing anything or touching it, the clock will stay at 3:00pm until I click the mouse or do something. If the computer sits there for 15 minutes, the next time I click the mouse, the time will jump from 3:00pm to 3:15pm.

What is going on here?

Comment: Have you already rebooted the computer to confirm the solution isn't as simple as that for a one-time fluke just in case? How long have you noticed this to be an issue?

Comment: When you run, winver, what build does it say you are running.  The reason I am asking this question, many people (over 100) have came here and said they are running the current version of Windows 10, only to find out they actually are not.  So its a common enough error, that its worth, verifying if you actually are running the current version.

Comment: @Ramhound It says version 1607 (OS Build 14393.105). I am using Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: @Homey_D_Clown_IT I just noticed it today. Yesterday it had a big update. I waited a long time and it restarted a few times. I am going to try reboot it tomorrow. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Homey_D_Clown_IT I rebooted the computer but the problem is still there.